# Wrap long lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, paste, word-wrap

I've noticed that <kbd>gq</kbd> does not work when I paste in a long line. For example, with a `textwidth=72` and `formatoptions=tcroqbnl`, gq refuses to wrap this (in insert mode, I pasted the entire label contents, and then exited insert mode with <kbd>ESC</kbd>):

```
<label for="contact_reason_1">To get assistance with or to confirm a tire replacement recommendation</label>
```

If I add a line break in (after "to", for example), it'll wrap then. The funny thing is if I join the line back together, it'll happily wrap it again. So VIM seems to somehow be remembering "oh, this is one paste, don't wrap it".

How do I turn that feature off? I'd like gq in command mode to *always* work. Taking `l` out of `formatoptions` did not seem to help (and it shouldn't, this isn't insert mode).

---

## clarification

Yes, I'm using a motion command, in particular, <kbd>gq<Right></kbd>. `formatexpr` and `formatprog` are both unset. If it matters, this is in gvim on Debian GNU/Linux, vim version 7.2p284.

## steps to reproduce

1. Pop up gvim on an open file.
2. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to get into insert mode, then type `This is a long line. A long line. But not wrappable yet. Or yet. Soon.`
3. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then <kbd>I</kbd>. Type `Now putting text in front of the long line.` *note: there is a space after the final period, can't get SO to show it, except when this note is here. FUN.*
4. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then <kbd>A</kbd>. Type `And some after.` *note: space before the And, same SO problem.*
5. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> one last time. Now try <kbd>gq<Left></kbd>, note it only wraps `And some after.`; I can't get vim to wrap the rest of the line (without going into insert mode and doing a line break by hand, then it works).

Fixing this state is doable; putting a newline after "now" and then hitting undo makes line wrap work again. WTF.

Comment: Reproduced and got a "good" result, sorry. Details under my answer.

Comment: Related: [Vim: The "gq" Command to Hard-Wrap Comments, but Not the Code (even if no blank line in-between)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13811219/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> isn't enough to wrap the text.  You have to give it a motion over which to wrap (like <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>) or tell it to wrap the current line with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.  Are you sure you're not just mistyping it?

If you aren't, what are the `formatexpr` and `formatprg` options set to, if anything?

**Update**
The problem is the b setting in `formatoptions`. That's telling Vim to only wrap the text added during the last insertion.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, +1

Comment: Yes, I'm giving it a motion. And it works on other lines, so I'm pretty sure it works. I've been trying gq<Right>, which normally works. I'll update the question.

Comment: The only situations where gq shouldn't be wrapping a line are 1) the line has no whitespace, 2) the line is shorter than 'textwidth', 3) 'formatexpr'/'formatprg' is set and the function/program that is invoked doesn't wrap the text.  Since none of these cases seem to be in play here, I'm not sure why you're seeing this behavior.

Comment: I've added some steps to reproduce a similar problem. Does this only happen for me? I tried it with gvim -u NONE, so it's not my vimrc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The problem is the b setting in `formatoptions`.  That's telling Vim to only wrap the text added during the last insertion.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed the `b` in `formatoptions`. Please edit this in to your answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1):

<s>I find that if I select the line before doing the gq, it works fine. Doesn't gq want to be combined with some text selection operation to work?</s>

**UPDATE**

I confirm the bug. Running vim -u NONE, my `formatoptions` are `vt`.

Maybe Bram Molenar or at least the vim community would be interested?

Comment: Please see my clarification & steps to reproduce.

Comment: I wasn't aware that a small motion like <kbd>left</kbd> would be enough to cause wrap, but sure enough! I faithfully followed your steps to reproduce and achieved a wrap just before "But," which looks entirely correct to me. I'm using vim 7.2.245 out of the box on Ubuntu 9.10 . I can do more testing if you tell me what.

Comment: "out of the box" was a lie. my .vimrc does: 
" Carl's vim settings
syn on
set sts=3
set ai
set sw=3

Comment: @Carl: Your distro (Ubuntu) probably has some customization in /etc/vim/vimrc and /etc/vim/gvimrc

Comment: @Carl: That `-u NONE` will skip system initialization in /etc as well; see `:help initialization` inside vim.

Comment: Re-tested with -u NONE and now it's behaving "badly" for me too. See update of my answer.