# Limit subject line of git commit message to 50 characters

Tags: git, vim

I often use `vim` to format my git commit messages.  A trend that I am seeing with [increasing](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#limit-50) [popularity](https://udacity.github.io/git-styleguide/) is that the first line of the commit message should be limited to 50 characters and then subsequent lines should be limited to 72 characters.

[I already know how to make my commit wrap at 72 characters based on my `vimrc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023194/automatically-wrap-long-git-commit-messages-in-vim):

```
syntax on
au FileType gitcommit set tw=72
```

Is there a way to make `vim` autowrap the first line at 50 characters and then 72 characters after that?

An equally good answer could highlight everything after the 50th column on **only** the first line to indicate that my header is too long ...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `CursorMoved` and `CursorMovedI` autocommands to set the desired textwidth (or any other setting) based on the line the cursor is currently on:

```
augroup gitsetup
        autocmd!

        " Only set these commands up for git commits
        autocmd FileType gitcommit
                \ autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI *
                        \ let &l:textwidth = line('.') == 1 ? 50 : 72
augroup end
```

The basic logic is simple: `let &l:textwidth = line('.') == 1 ? 50 : 72`, although the nested autocommands make it look rather funky. You could extract some of it out to a script-local function (`fun! s:setup_git()`) and call that, if you prefer.

The `&:l` syntax is the same as `setlocal`, by the way (but with `setlocal` we can't use an expression such as on the right-hand-side, only a simple string).

Some related questions:

- [Line number specific text-width setting](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9174/51).
- [Set paste mode when at beginning of line but auto-indent mode when anywhere else on the line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3650/51)

---

Note that the default `gitcommit.vim` syntax file already stops highlighting the first line after 50 characters. From `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/gitcommit.vim`:

```
syn match   gitcommitSummary    "^.\{0,50\}" contained containedin=gitcommitFirstLine nextgroup=gitcommitOverflow contains=@Spell
[..]
hi def link gitcommitSummary        Keyword
```

*Only* the first 50 lines get highlighted as a "Keyword" (light brown in my colour scheme), after that no highlighting is applied.

If also has:

```
syn match   gitcommitOverflow   ".*" contained contains=@Spell
[..]
"hi def link gitcommitOverflow      Error
```

Notice how it's commented out, probably because it's a bit too opinionated. You can easily add this to your vimrc though:

```
augroup gitsetup
        autocmd!

        " Only set these commands up for git commits
        autocmd FileType gitcommit
                \  hi def link gitcommitOverflow Error
                \| autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI *
                        \  let &l:textwidth = line('.') == 1 ? 50 : 72
augroup end
```

Which will make everything after 50 characters show up as an error (you could, if you want, also use less obtrusive colours by choosing a different highlight group).

Comment: Great answer, and I haven't seen the `&l:` trick before, that's going to be useful!