# Vim: The "gq" Command to Hard-Wrap Comments, but Not the Code (even if no blank line in-between)

Tags: vim, format, comments

My Vim configuration includes `set formatoptions=c,q,a`. I am completely annoyed with the following problem (`|` denotes cursor position, its exact position does not matter, as you probably know only the fact of its presence in this commented line matters):

```
" This is a long line which we would like to wrap. However, something sick is go|ing to happen if we hit "gqip" here!
if has('win32') || has('win64')
  set runtimepath^=~/.vim
  set runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
endif
```

Now we hit `gqip`:

```
" This is a long line which we would like to wrap. However, something sick is
" go|ing to happen if we hit "gqip" here!
if has('win32') || has('win64') set runtimepath^=~/.vim set
  runtimepath+=~/.vim/after endif
```

What it does is - it actually treats the whole thing as a single paragraph. (Yes, I know that separating with a blank line prevents this behavior, but it does not solve the problem!) What I would like it to be is indeed:

```
" This is a long line which we would like to wrap. However, something sick is
" go|ing to happen if we hit "gqip" here!
if has('win32') || has('win64')
  set runtimepath^=~/.vim
  set runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
endif
```

In other words, it would be great if `gq` could somehow forget about the code and work only with comments.

**BONUS:** How to do this formatting (wrapping comments **only**) on the whole buffer in one shot? Because, ideally I would like to move that stuff to a special formatting hook for file saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With my [SameSyntaxMotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4338), you can use the `ay` text object to represent the entire block of comments the cursor is in, and re-format it using `gqay`.

Comment: Sick stuff man, good job, thank you for sharing this plugin. Just a remark - it was a bit cumbersome to install it due to `vimball`-packaging since I use pathogen. Also, I feel like a much better name would be `SyntaxGroupMotion`, it will be much easier to find then and more intuitive. Now a question - it works fine with the default mapping `y` and `Y`, but I tried to remap it to `g` and `G` (following that "group" mnemonic) and I was out of luck. What's the trick here?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it does remap it to `g`. The problem was with mapping the combination like this `nnoremap <C-f> gwag`. Be careful, one should rather map it like this `nmap <C-f> gwag`, otherwise it cannot catch the `g` mapping of the plugin.

Answer (score 17):

> it actually treats the whole thing as a single paragraph

Well, with `gqip`, you told it to! You need to choose the right motion. In this case of a single line, it would be `gqq`. For 3 lines, that's `gq2j`. If it's too many lines to count, use visual mode: `Vjjjjjjgq`.

Comment: This is something counter-intuitive in this context. What you really want Vim to do in this case is to think of multiple lines of comments (without blank lines in-between) as paragraphs of its own, regardless of whether they are separated with blank lines (above and below) from the code. The code is code, comments are comments. Counting how many lines of comments to wrap each time is annoying, and wastes one's time, even though it seems like fast action - the time actually tends to accumulate you know. Is there a way I can teach Vim to treat comments as a paragraph, regardless of separation?

Comment: I really expected to see such behavior out of the box because of `q` in `formatoptions`, however it turns out not to be the case, which is a big misfortune I think.

Comment: The other way around, as you mentioned, is to provide a correct motion. Can you come up with a generic (working for comments in any language, possibly utilizing some variable which denotes current comment leader) motion so that when I'm inside such comment block it goes to the beginning (when there is no adjacent commented line **above**) of this block and selects text until the end (when there is no adjacent commented line **below**) of this block. This would indeed, do the trick.

Comment: It's indeed surprising that Vim doesn't support this better. Comments are just a special case of syntax highlighting, there's very little core support. Interestingly, I've written a plugin to define a text object based on syntax highlighting. Check out my other answer.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the `ip` text object is rather narrow, as @IngoKarkat pointed out: it is simply any text paragraph delimited by blank lines.

I have also created a plugin that you could use to address this problem.

> [***textobj-comment***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4570) - Text objects for comments

In contrast with the *SameSyntaxMotion* plugin, *textobj-comment* relies on the filetype-specific `'comments'` setting to identify comments. That means it should work even with syntax-highlighting turned off.

Use `gqic` to format a comment.

Pro tip: Prefer [`gw`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gw) over `gq` as it preserves the cursor position.

Comment: plus 1 for including the pathogen install lines, so i could cut and paste them right into my terminal.   by nice if it could leave comments hanging at the end of the line, and then indent to that spot

Answer (score 2):

Search for commented lines using `:g`, then wrap those lines:

```
:%g/^"/normal gq_
```

Comment: Your solution wraps individual lines, while the main goal was to wrap **paragraphs** of comments - which is more generic. Another disadvantage is that you have hard-coded the comment leader `"` for VimL. It's better to come up with a generic solution, for any programming language (or at least any), which is straightforward if one has access to a variable which stores current comment leader. I myself just don't know what's the name of the variable and whether it exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I found this question while investigating the same problem myself. How about:

```
set formatprg=fmt\ --prefix='\"'
```

With that gqip seems to behave as required. I will definitely be checking out the SameSyntaxMotion plugin though.